# Yodlee API return error with data encrypted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yodlee

I'm building an app using yodlee and rails, everything works fine on sandbox, the problem it's when I use the live env, with the PKI feature.

I'm getting my API key from [here](https://developer.yodlee.com/apidocs/index.php#!/cobrand/publicKey)

Then I'm using these lines of code to encrypt the sensitive information (username/password/pin)

```
  key= public_key
  rsa_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(key.keyAsPemString)
  key.keyAlias + ":" +Base64.encode64(rsa_key.public_encrypt(value_to_encrypt))
```

I send the request but I'm getting this

```
 {"errorCode"=>"Y400", "errorMessage"=>"Decryption failure for FieldInfo:FieldInfoSingle: {FieldInfo: name=\"LOGIN\" displayName=\"null\" editable=true optional=false helpText=\"null\" valuePattern=\"null\" } defaultValue=\"null\" value=\"\" validValues=[null] displayValidValues=[null] valueIdentifier=\"null\" valueMask=\"null\" fieldType=\"TEXT\" validationRules=[null] size=null maxlength=null userProfileMappingExpression=null fieldErrorCode=null fieldErrorMessage=null ", "referenceCode"=>"RB_3cf12f35-05d3-4d87-a1f9-edcfc62df3d2"}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only difference from the [official Java version](https://developer.yodlee.com/Yodlee_API/Yodlee_API_PKI_Feature) of the encryption code seems to be the final encoding. It should be **[hex-encoded](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/digest/rdoc/Digest.html#method-c-hexencode)**, not Base64-encoded. Try this instead:

```
key.keyAlias + ":" + Digest.hexencode(rsa_key.public_encrypt(value_to_encrypt))
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like in your live environment PKI feature is not enabled correctly. Please ask Yodlee support team to either enable or disable PKI based on your need. Once they do that it should work as expected.